# Long running query on a self joined table

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I try to improve the performance of a query which updates a coloumn on each row of a table, by comparing the actual row's values with all other rows in the same table. Here is the query:

```
update  F set   
    PartOfPairRC = 1
from    RangeChange F
where     Reject=0
and exists( 
            select 1 from RangeChange S
            where   F.StoreID = S.StoreID
            and F.ItemNo = S.ItemNo
            and       F.Reject = S.Reject
            and F.ChangeDateEnd = S.ChangeDate - 1)
```

The query's performance degrades rapidly as the number of rows in the table increases. I have 50 millon rows in the table.

Is there a better way to do this? Would SSIS be able to handle such an operation better?

Any help much appreciated, thanks Robert

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a index on that table:

```
create index idx_test on RangeChange(StoreID, ItemNo, Reject, ChangeDateEnd) where reject = 0
```

--when you are not using the SQL enterprise get rid of the where condition in the index and put the reject column as included column in the index
--make sure you have a clustered index already on the table (when not you can create the index above as clustered)

-- I would write the query as a join:

```
update F set
   F.PartOfPairRC = 1
from  RangeChange F
   join RangeChange S
      on F.StoreID = S.StoreID
         and F.ItemNo = S.ItemNo
         and F.Reject = S.Reject
         and F.ChangeDateEnd = S.ChangeDate - 1
where F.Reject=0 and S.Reject = 0
```

Comment: you risk more writing to the database this way.

Comment: Thanks, Michal. The original code (which I'm only reviewing) did include a create index as: create clustered index IXC_RangeChange 
 on RangeChange (StoreID,ItemNo,ChangeDate)
This did not include Reject, and also, should ChangeDateEnd being included in the index as well? Is non-clustered index better here? Does it make significant difference using Join, rather than just where clauses? Many thanks, Robert